# How to output XML in HTML format

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have project that I'm currently trying to customize. I'm trying to create store locator application using HTML and calling a url to output data with a XML format.

The input form I'm using accepts parameters:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Store Locator</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   </head>
  <body>

    <div align="center">
        <form action="SmartHomePage2.html" method="post">
            <table cellspacing="5">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <h2>Store Locator</h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        Enter Your Zip Code: 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="zip" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">
                        Enter the search radius in miles: 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="dist" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

And here is what my output page looks like:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Search Results</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Best Buy Results</h1>
        <c:import url="http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/stores(area
                (${param.zip},${param.dist}))?show=storeId,name,distance,lat,lng
                &apiKey=ruuk8c4ux2p4e7d6bfftzuda" var="message" />
            <x:parse var="a" doc="${message}" />
            <x:forEach var="current" select="$a/stores/store">
                        <b> Store ID: </b> <x:out select="$current/storeId" /> 
                            <br />
                        <b> Name: </b> <x:out select="$current/name" /> 
                            <br />
                        <b> Distance: </b> <x:out select="$current/distance" /> 
                            <br />
                        <b> Latitude: </b> <x:out select="$current/lat" /> 
                            <br />
                        <b> Longitude: </b> <x:out select="$current/lng" /> 
                            <br />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </x:forEach>

    </body>
</html>
```

My question would be how to output XML data with HTML? Or do I need to incorporate some JavaScript?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using **XSL**, here's a good explanation and example.

[Converting XML to HTML using XSL](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/xml/converting-xml-to-html-using-xsl.html)

Comment: Great Article, Thank you for advice, just what I needed!

Comment: No problem. ^_^ -Cheers!